# pgfplots colorbar horizontal changes filling

Tags: pgfplots

I want two heatmaps within one figure and the colorbars should be below the two pictures. Unfortunately, with the `colorbar horizontal` option, one of the colorbars has no color for the highest value. How can I fix this?

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}
```

```
\begin{figure}[tb]
    \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
          \begin{axis}[width=0.45\linewidth,enlargelimits=false,colorbar,colormap/Blues,ticklabel style = {font=\small},at={(0,0)},colorbar horizontal]
            \addplot [matrix plot,point meta=explicit]
              coordinates {
                (0,0) [12.1337814] (1,0) [20.20624204] (2,0) [0.72550741] (3,0) [4.50361657] (4,0) [5.94018956]
        
                (0,1) [3.93110895] (1,1) [18.97859117] (2,1) [14.01737163] (3,1) [2.21380307] (4,1) [4.99754559]
        
                %... and so on
              };
          \end{axis}
          \node[] at (-.6,4) {(a)};

          \begin{axis}[width=0.45\linewidth,enlargelimits=false,colorbar,colormap/Blues,ticklabel style = {font=\small},at={(0.45\linewidth,0)},colorbar horizontal]
            \addplot [matrix plot,point meta=explicit]
              coordinates {
                (0,0) [1.17318609] (1,0) [1.05299383] (2,0) [1.16487899] (3,0) [1.29665568] (4,0) [1.0800012] (5,0) [1.4084673] (6,0) [1.44914629] (7,0) [1.04543044] (8,0) [0.94458378] (9,0) [0.94537562]
                
                (0,1) [1.00856655] (1,1) [1.04160759] (2,1) [1.03695704] (3,1) [1.07905316] (4,1) [1.12535244] (5,1) [1.12676269] (6,1) [1.03765699] (7,1) [1.00644902] (8,1) [0.90470504] (9,1) [1.06445035]
                
                %... and so on
              };
          \end{axis}
          \node[] at (6,4) {(b)};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption[Heat Map]{Caption...}
    \label{fig:heatmap}
\end{figure}
```

Here are two pictures showing what I mean. The right colorbar is changing. Please ignore the overlapping in the first picture -> this is the reason I want the horizontal colorbar

Without `colorbar horizontal`

[image]

With `colorbar horizontal`

[image]

Comment: Please provide a (full working) [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) the next time you ask a question. Then we -- the helpers -- can concentrate on *solving* the problem instead of first investing time to make it work ...

Comment: In addition, the given data produce the expected colorbar, thus we can't even reproduce your problem since you didn't provide all relevant data points (min/max z) values ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I just found the solution to my problem. But the answer to why `colorbar horizontal` is changing the settings is still pending and would still interest me.

I could fix it with setting `point meta max=1.8` in the second heatmap:

```
\begin{axis}[width=0.45\linewidth,enlargelimits=false,colorbar,colormap/Blues,ticklabel style = {font=\small},at={(0.45\linewidth,0)},colorbar horizontal,point meta max=1.8]
```

[image]